# Переход на URL с помощью JS

Tags: php, javascript

Доброго времени суток, господа.

Есть страница. Внутри код php. Требуется (без функции header) код, при вставке которого на страницу произойдет перепрыгивание на другую страницу. Скажем после задержки в 1000мс. Подскажите решение. Что-то вроде js кода. Вставил, и через 1000мс после нахождение на странице - переход на указанный url.

P.S. Где-то на просторах хэшкода аналогичная тема была, но не на ajax, а на js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setInterval('window.location.href = "http://google.com"', 1000);
```

Comment: спасибо огромное

Comment: setInterval-то зачем? Если браузер с первого раза не поймёт, повторить?)

Comment: точно, перепутал их

Answer (score 8):

Простейший редирект с задержкой:

```
setTimeout(function(){window.location.href='http://ya.ru/';}, 1000);
```

Comment: тож отличное решение. жаль нельзя влепить "accept 2x"

Comment: @mixalef Это решение лучше :)

Answer (score 5):

Без `JS`:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="1;URL=http://ya.ru/">
</head>
```

Comment: оба на, вот так поворот! супер. беру на вооружение

Answer (score 2):

```
 function goToOtherPage() {
     window.location.href = "http://www.yandex.ru/";
 }

 window.setTimeout(goToOtherPage, 1000);
```

Comment: А чем Ваше решение отличается от чуть выше данного, кроме именованной функции?

Comment: <sarcasm>больше кода - больше денег</sarcasm> :)

Answer (score 0):

```
this.showView = function () {
$timeout(function() {
        var redirectWindow = window.open('http://google.com','_self');
        redirectWindow.location;
}, 550);
};
```

Этот фокус обойдет popup-blocker